# Not a group expression: troubleshooting an Oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle query
I have a column value with hardcoded value 'N/A' and other char values as well. I need to write a select query to get the min of this column grouping the other set of columns.. but the challenge is i need to replace the hard coded value of 'N/A' with another character 'Abc' along with min function

Option 1: nvl won't work as the value is hardcoded
Option 2: decode in the select statement along with min clause in the decode list, and group by clause with the other columns used in the select list
However,  getting an error

> **ORA-00979** : not a group expression.

Example :

```
Select a, b, decode(z,'N/A','abc',min(z)) 
  From table 1, table 2
 Where table 1.p=table2.q
 Group by a,b
Having c.table1 >= table2.d
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `DECODE` inside the `MIN` function, not the other way around.  But, I would probably just use a single `CASE` expression here:

```
SELECT
    a,
    b,
    MIN(CASE WHEN z = 'N/A' THEN 'abc' ELSE z END) AS min_value
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.p = t2.q
GROUP BY
    a,
    b;
```

The above `CASE` expression is just taking the minimum value of `z` for each group, with the only difference between `MIN(z)` being that should the value be `N/A`, it would be treated as `abc`.